# Overflow scroll has overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a div scrollable content and in it is a header that should overflow its parent.
It seems that overflow: scroll adds overflow: hidden to the element.
If you could help me I would appreciate it. Thanks!

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="problem">This is hidden</div>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="container container-2">
    <div class="problem">This is what i want, but scrollable.</div>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 230px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.container-2 {
    overflow-y: visible;
}

.problem {
    width: 235px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #33CCFF;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.problem {
    width: 235px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #33CCFF;
    /*margin-left: -20px;*/  //this is the cause of problem comment this
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBE74/)

Comment: The idea is that I want the blue div to be a little bit outside of its parent like it is in the last one, but in the first one the overflow hides it.

Comment: @LucaBoieru like the second one is going in right, or you want it to the left

Comment: I want the blue div to be outside to the left (see the original code of the second example)